# Swift Tour Card.createDeck() Returning [{(enum value), (enum value)}]

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am completing the Apple Swift tour, and am running into trouble with return enum values.  My code seems to be running fine, but when I create a deck of cards, the appropriate rank and suit are not returned, I just get `[{(enum value), (enum value)}]` returned 52 times.

Apparently there was a bug causing this when Swift first came out, but it was fixed a while ago with Xcode 6.3 I believe, (I am running Xcode 6.4), so I don't see how that could be the issue.

I've been able to resolve the problem in some circumstances by using `.simpleDescription` to return the actual string but I can't seem to get that to work in this instance.

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "ace"
        case .Jack:
            return "jack"
        case .Queen:
            return "queen"
        case .King:
            return "king"
        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

enum Suit  {
    case Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Spades:
            return "spades"
        case .Hearts:
            return "hearts"
        case .Diamonds:
            return "diamonds"
        case .Clubs:
            return "clubs"
        }
    }
    static func color(suitName: Suit) -> String {
        if(suitName.simpleDescription() == "spades" || suitName.simpleDescription() == "clubs") {
            return "Black"
        } else {
            return "Red"
        }
    }
}

struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }
    static func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        let ranks = [Rank.Ace, Rank.Two, Rank.Three, Rank.Four, Rank.Five, Rank.Six, Rank.Seven, Rank.Eight, Rank.Nine, Rank.Ten, Rank.Jack, Rank.Queen, Rank.King]
        let suits = [Suit.Spades, Suit.Hearts, Suit.Diamonds, Suit.Clubs]
        var deck = [Card]()
        for suit in suits {
            for rank in ranks {
                deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            }
        }
        println(deck)
        return deck
    }
}
let threeOfSpades = Card(rank: .Three, suit: .Spades)
let threeOfSpadesDescription = threeOfSpades.simpleDescription() // This code returns the card properly

Card.createDeck()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way it is. `println` doesn't show enum values. Implement Printable (and `description`), or update to Swift 2.0, which fixes it.