# Need clarification on Enumeration types in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to understand Enumerations in Swift but I am confused about the assignment to a variable. Here is an example:

```
enum Planet {
    case Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune
}

var myPlanet = Planet.Mercury
```

I am confused about the last line. Is *myPlanet* variable being assigned a **Planet** object with case **Mercury** as its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a Planet "Object" because Swift prefers the term "Type". An "Object" implies that it's an instance of a "class." Classes, enums & structs in Swift sort of blur the lines a bit vs. other languages.

`Planet` is not a class, but an enumeration - a collection of related "member values". You're literally counting or "enumerating" all the various options within the group, and saying what name each one should go by. This provides a helpful alias to each value, allowing you to refer to the planets by name, instead of saying "Planet #1, #2, #3, #4, #5..."

Any situation where you have a finite collection of equal options may be a good candidate for an enum: "North, South, East, West" is another common example.

What you're doing here is declaring a new variable `myPlanet`, and assigning its initial value to the `Planet` enum's member value `Mercury`. The `Planet` Type is not explicitly declared, but is inferred from context - this new variable *must* be of Type `Planet` in order to hold the desired value of `.Mercury`.

An alternative declaration would be: `var myPlanet: Planet = .Mercury`
By *explicitly* declaring the Type of the var to be a `Planet` you can omit `Planet` from the righthand side.

Also, since it's a `var` & not `let` you could later change `myPlanet` to any of the "member values" of the Planet enum. Since `myPlanet` can only be 1 of the possible `Planet` options, you only need to refer to the member value:

`myPlanet = .Earth`

You could not, however, change `myPlanet` to a different Type (whether enum, struct, or class), because its type was already defined as `Planet`.

See the Enumerations chapter of the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) for more examples/details (though this example is the same, so you're probably reading it).

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:**

> To me Planet.Mercury means an enumeration type called Planet with only case Mercury inside of it.

Your `myPlanet` *variable* is of Type Planet, with only the *value* `.Mercury` assigned to it. "Planet.Mercury" as a statement is like pointing to "Menu of Planets, Value: Mercury."

A basic enum is a list of possible options, like a menu:

```
List of Planets to Choose From
1. Mercury
2. Venus
3. Earth
4. etc...
```

The variable `myPlanet` is a container that can only have 1 value at a time. 
Since you set it to 1 of the options listed within the `Planet` enum definition, Swift infers that it must be of Type `Planet`. From that point forward, this container is marked "Only For Planets" and its assigned value can only come from the enum list. The `Planet` enum itself is static - it's the restaurant menu and always contains the same options (unless you edit the enum definition itself).

> If I were to write it in terms of a class called Planet, I see it as myPlanet = Planet(name: "Mercury"). Do you have an analogy that can help me grasp the enumeration concept? –  Walter

With the class example, you'd be using a method to initialize a `Planet` instance with a property `name` that you set to the String "Mercury". This is different in a number of ways. For one, "name" in this case is a property of Type String, which has getter/setter methods, etc. You could presumably set `name` to whatever you want: `Planet.name = "Walter"`  You also have to access the property by its name, and provide it with a value. This is not true of enums.

With an enum, all you have is the predefined list of possible options. 
Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, etc. The enum's "member values" are simply nicknames, similar to an alias for "Entry #1, Entry #2, Entry #3". If "Planet.Walter" is not in the predefined list, you cannot assign a variable of Type Planet to that value. It knows it has to be a `Planet` but it won't find `case Walter` among the options.

> Also, the reason I am still confused has to do with accessing computed properties inside the enumeration. For example, if I had a computed property called size that is based on self inside the enumeration based on, the way to access is myPlanet.size. This means that it is equivalent to Planet.Mercury.size. How am I accessing a computed property through the case >value Mercury?

Computed properties are one of the places where Swift blurs the lines of traditional Object-Oriented Programming, because they exist in classes, enums, and structs, so it can get confusing.

`myPlanet.size` doesn't necessarily equal `Planet.Mercury.size` - it could be `Planet.size` where size is a computed property returned from a function within the enum itself. 
See this question for an example: 
[Swift Tour Card.createDeck() Returning [{(enum value), (enum value)}]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900326/swift-tour-card-createdeck-returning-enum-value-enum-value)

The following is an untested variation on the card deck example:

```
enum Planet {
    case Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars

    func size() -> String {
       switch self {
          case .Mercury:
            return "pretty darn small!"
          case .Venus:
            return "still small!"
          case .Earth:
            return "we think this is normal"
          case .Mars:
            return "slightly bigger than Earth"
      }
    }

}

var myPlanet: Planet = .Mercury
print(\myPlanet.size()) //"pretty darn small!"
myPlanet = .Mars
print(\myPlanet.size()) //"slightly bigger than Earth"
```

With this approach, the "size" function is a method of the `Planet` enum, similar to how an object can have instance methods, or a struct can have methods too. Calling `myPlanet.size()` after assigning a value is like saying "I'm a Type Planet, so if I look at myself, I know I'm a Mercury, so when I execute this method I have because I'm a Planet, I return the value for Mercury." Change the assigned value, and the method remains the same, but the returned value is now different, because myPlanet now has a different value.

Comment: Here is my confusion. I know that Planet is an enumeration data type and not an object. But for some reason I see it as an object. To me **Planet.Mercury** means *an enumeration type called **Planet** with only **case Mercury** inside of it*.  If I were to write it in terms of a class called Planet, I see it as **myPlanet = Planet(name: "Mercury")**. Do you have an analogy that can help me grasp the enumeration concept?

Comment: Also, the reason I am still confused has to do with accessing computed properties inside the enumeration. For example, if I had a computed property called **size** inside the enumeration, the way to access it is by **myPlanet.size**. This means that **myPlanet.size** is equivalent to **Planet.Mercury.size**. How am I accessing a computed property through the case value **Mercury**?

Comment: I like to think of the enumeration `Planet` as a new *type* you've defined, with those 8 possibilities (*members*) you listed out. Just like `Int` is a type with `2 * Int.max` possibilities, and `Bool` is a type with two possibilities. Does that analogy make more sense?

Comment: Hi @WalterM - I added a bit to (hopefully) clarify & expand based on your comments. Think of an enum like a restaurant menu - it's a list of options to choose from & doesn't change when make your choice & assign it to your "order" variable. The menu itself may also have "computed properties" that apply to every item, or that vary based on the item.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is an *object* that you're assigning to `myPlanet`. You're assigning `myPlanet` with `Mercury`, which is a *member* of the *enumeration* `Planet`. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) states:

> If you are familiar with C, you will know that C enumerations assign related names to a set of integer values. Enumerations in Swift are much more flexible, and do not have to provide a value for each member of the enumeration. If a value (known as a “raw” value) is provided for each enumeration member, the value can be a string, a character, or a value of any integer or floating-point type.

They go on to elaborate on this further (answering your question, in my opinion):

> The values defined in an enumeration (such as `North`, `South`, `East`, and `West`) are the member values (or members) of that enumeration. The `case` keyword indicates that a new line of member values is about to be defined.
>
> > NOTE
> >
> > Unlike C and Objective-C, Swift enumeration members are not assigned a default integer value when they are created. In the `CompassPoint` example above, `North`, `South`, `East` and `West` do not implicitly equal `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. Instead, the different enumeration members are fully-fledged values in their own right, with an explicitly-defined type of `CompassPoint`.

---

You're not entirely wrong in thinking of the assigned value as an *object*, though – as the [documentation continues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) with:

> Enumerations in Swift are first-class types in their own right. They adopt many features traditionally supported only by classes, such as computed properties to provide additional information about the enumeration’s current value, and instance methods to provide functionality related to the values the enumeration represents. Enumerations can also define initializers to provide an initial member value; can be extended to expand their functionality beyond their original implementation; and can conform to protocols to provide standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Swift enumerations do not work the same way as in Objective C.

The values which are stored inside of them cannot be used on their own (unless the type can be inferred). In the example below type can be inferred:

```
var myPlanet:Planet = .Mercury
```

First you are telling compiler that the variable is of type Planet and then you can use shorthand notation.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) is pretty good on enumerations and I strongly encourage you to read it: